# Docker login issue with Harbor exposed as NodePort service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop, harbor

I am trying to deploy Harbor on a k8s cluster without much efforts and complexity. So, I followed the [Bitnami Harbor Helm chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/harbor/helm) and deployed a healthy running Harbor instance that is exposed as a NodePort service. I know that the standard is to have a LoadBalancer type of service but as I don't have required setup to provision a requested load balancer automatically, I decided to stay away from that complexity. This is not a public cloud environment where the LB gets deployed automatically.

Now, I can very well access the Harbor GUI using `https://<node-ip>:<https-port>` URL. However, despite several attempts I cannot connect to this Harbor instance from my local Docker Desktop instance. I have also imported the CA in my machine's keychain, but as the certificate has a dummy domain name in it rather than the IP address, Docker doesn't trust that Harbor endpoint. So, I created a local DNS record in my `/etc/hosts` file to link the domain name in Harbor's certificate and the node IP address of the cluster. With that arrangement, Docker seems to be happy with the certificate presented but it doesn't acknowledge the port required to access the endpoint. So, in the subsequent internal calls for authentication against Harbor, it fails with below given error. Then I also tried to follow the advice given here on Harbor document to connect to Harbor over HTTP. But this configuration killed Docker daemon and does not let it even start.

```
~/.docker » docker login -u admin https://core.harbor.domain:30908                                
Password:
Error response from daemon: Get "https://core.harbor.domain:30908/v2/": Get "https://core.harbor.domain/service/token?account=admin&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=harbor-registry": EOF
```

As you can see in above error, the second Get URL does not have a port in it, which would not work.
So, is there any help can I get to configure my Docker Desktop to connect to a Harbor service running on the NodePort interface? I use Docker Desktop on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar  Error when I used 'docker login core.harbor.domain:30003' from another Host. The  Error likes 'Error response from daemon: Get https://core.harbor.domain:30003/v2/: Get https://core.harbor.domain/service/token?account=admin&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=harbor-registry: dial tcp 1.*.*.*:443: connect: connection refused'.
However,docker can login harbor from the host  on which the helm chart installed harbor.

Comment: I was trying it from the same workstation that I used to deploy Harbor using the Helm chart. Finally, I concluded that Docker daemon does not entertain any port other than 443 and 80.